# iterate over std::vector of std::vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have a std::vector of std::vector container like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> >
```

I want to pass this container to a "C" library. 
This library iterates over this data with an int** variable.
For example:

```
int** data;
...
data[i][j] = 42;
```

or

```
*(data[i]+j) = 42
```

How could I assign my data to this double pointer and iterate over it?
Thanks in advance?

Comment: C does not have `std` or `vector` or templates.  Remove the `C` tag from this question